# Status: 500 Internal Server Error when running symfony2 console command thorugh CRON job

Tags: php, symfony, cron, shared-hosting

I fall a little short when working with servers so I would need some help here.

I have created a symfony 2 console command (nothing fancy just a quick DB update). Everything works fine when I SSh to my host and call the command through the terminal. But when I add it to the CRON job I always get the following error to my email:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-type: text/html
```

There was a problem through terminal because my hosting has register_argc_argv set on OFF by default so I wasn't being able to use PHP command line parameters. I have created my own custom php.ini and override that setting so as I said everything works as it should if I run it from terminal.

In CRON I have tired:

- by using custom php.ini (used master form server but tweaked the register_argc_argv to ON) got Failed loading ZendGuardLoader error
- with php -d register_argc_argv=1 "my command"
- with php-cli mycommand

All fired through terminal, but with CRON no luck...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does the command look you run over ssh? Also could you post the `crontab` entry you have tried?

Comment: You should check if the cron is running under the same custom php.ini and also the same *nix user as your ssh session

Comment: In terminal I run: php -d register_argc_argv=1 /home2/username/develop/app/console stat:new, I post the same command to CRON adding * * * * * to run it every minute

Comment: @J.T. may be cron uses different config file, for ex. cli/php.ini?

Comment: How could I check, see its location?

Comment: @J.T. you can try to create a simple bash script which outputs 'php -i', then execute it by cron

Comment: one more tip, if you change any cron settings, don't forget to restart the cron service

Comment: @xurshid29 There were two different php.ini files for web and cron, but the cron one has register_argc_argv ON by default... So I really don't know what could be wrong now? Since I get nothing else from my cron report than 500 Internal Server Error...

Comment: @J.T. there can be other reasons which can cause 500 error, such as not enough execution time (max_execution_time), folder permissions, wrong path to the console file, etc...

Comment: I know, but script literary runs for a couple of ms (only adds a single row to DB), the path is taken from my hosting provider support pages for making CRON jobs and should be correct... could the problem be that the app folder is outside the public_html folder?

Comment: @J.T. can you show your crontask rule?

Comment: Crontask rule? This is the whole command I'm running * * * * * php/home2/username/develop/app/console stat:new